# How to logout with openid_client after authentication via pkce in flutter app with keycloak using openid_client?

Tags: flutter, keycloak, openid, logout

I have the following KeyCloak Client config, to use pkce authentication flow:

```
Realm: REALM

Client ID:              pkce-client
Client Protocol:        openid-connect
Access Type:            public
Standard Flow Enabled:  ON
Valid Redirect URIs:    http://localhost:4200/ 

Advanced Settings:
Proof Key for Code Exchange Code Challenge Method: S256
```

After authenticating with flutter App with iOS Simulator via openid_client
https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client at some point I need to log out.

I can do this to get the logout URL:

```
    String localhost = getLocalhost();

var uri = Uri.parse('http://$localhost:8180/auth/realms/REALM');

var clientId = 'pkce-client';

var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
var client = Client(issuer, clientId);

String idT = token.idToken.toCompactSerialization();
Credential credential = client.createCredential(
  tokenType: token.tokenType,
  refreshToken: token.refreshToken,
  idToken: idT,
);

 var url;
try {
  url = credential.generateLogoutUrl();
} catch (e) {
  print("Error during login (refresh) " + e.toString());

}
      urlLauncher(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
  String callUrl = url.toString();
  urlLauncher.call(callUrl);
```

This is how the logout url looks like:

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/vopi/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIxUVJwMXAtbmk1WmcyZmlyRHFoRS1iS1hwe.......
```

I'm not logged out after calling the url. Can someone help with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Redirect browser (web view) to that logout url (logout URL is not an API call, so you can't use XMLHttpRequest). That terminates existing IdP session. Of course you need to destroy also any local tokens (access/id/refresh token), which your app already has.

Answer (score 1):

the IDP should have a front end logout url that you can call to logout of the current session. it is a call directly from the browser to the IDP endpoint.

the IDP front end logout should terminate the session, clear any cookies but the backend tokens (access token , refresh token etc) need to be cleared by your application.